# Really really slow precompilation, rails 3.2

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ckeditor, assets

I have an app using both bootstrap-sass and ckeditor, so it's quite heavy assets-wise. So I'm used to precompiling taking a few minutes.

However, lately precompiling is taking more and more time, until today it took over 15 minutes! Precompiling locally also takes way too long, so I still need a long time whenever the assets get changed.

Any advice?
I could paste in some code, only I'm not sure where to start.

**EDIT:**

BTW, I'm using Windows, which I know is not ideal, but it's my main working environment. I tried precompiling on a mac, and it did it in more than 6 minutes. Much faster, but still not good.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with rails 3.2.13. If you can, downgrade to 3.2.12 until the fix goes live or upgrade to rails 4.0.0.